# Ring of integers of local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_ p,$ and $\mathcal O$ the ring of integers of $K$. Let $\mathfrak p$ be the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O$.

Is it true that the quotient ring $\mathcal O/\mathfrak p^n$ is finite for all $n>0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, without using topology, this follows easily from the fact that $\mathcal{O}$ is a DVR. Namely, I'm sure you know that $k:=\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}$ is finite (this is one of the axioms of a local field--depending on what your definition is). Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer for $\mathcal{O}$. Then, consider the map

$$\varphi:\mathcal{O}\to \mathfrak{p}^n/\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}:x\mapsto \pi^nx+\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}$$

This is clearly a surjective homomorphism of abelian groups. Moreover, it's clear that $\ker\varphi=\mathfrak{p}$. Thus, we obtain an isomorphism of abelian groups $k=\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}\cong \mathfrak{p}^n/\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}$. In fact, if you stare at this for a second, you see this an isomorphism of $k$-spaces. Since we have the filtration of $k$-subspaces

$$\{0\}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}^{n-1}/\mathfrak{p}^n\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n$$

of $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n$. Since each subsequent quotient $(\mathfrak{p}^j/\mathfrak{p}^n)/(\mathfrak{p}^{j+1}/\mathfrak{p}^n)\cong \mathfrak{p}^j/\mathfrak{p}^{j+1}\cong k$ is one-dimensional this implies that $\dim_k \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n=n$. Thus, $|\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n|=|k|^n<\infty$.

Comment: Which book makes the assumption that $\mathcal{O}\backslash \mathcal{p}$ is finite? Notice I am not challenging you but rather wondering. What about power series rings?

Comment: @Luis Did you think I meant for a DVR? I'm sorry that wasn't clear--it's one of the equivalent definitions of a local field.

Comment: Dear @Luis, The standard definition of a local field is a non-discrete locally compact topological field. In the non-Archimedean case, the local compactness implies finiteness of the residue field.

Comment: In fact, some people define local fields (excluding $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) as being complete, non-archimedean local fields with finite residue field :)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Oops, I meant to say 'discrete' instead of 'non-archimedean'.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Well then, something is wrong. It is true that non-archimedean fields are local if and only if discretely valued, complete, and finite residue field. I could tell you the proof? Isn't the residue field of the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11764/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-bruno-joyal)

Comment: @AlexYoucis thank you

Answer (score 6):

Yes, because $\mathcal O$ is compact, and $\mathfrak p^n$ is open.

Comment: thanks Bruno Joyal, you have a reference in which I find proof?

Comment: @Amine My pleasure. As a reference, you can use Serre's *Local Fields*, or any book on local fields really. Or you can try to prove it yourself, which is much better.

Comment: thank you for correcting, my English is poor. :)

Comment: @Amine Don't worry about it! :)