# Number of elements in $D/P^e$ where $D$ is a ring of algebraic integers, and $P$ a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

This is from Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*.

> Proposition 12.3.2: Consider a field $F/\mathbb Q$ with ring of integers $D$, and a prime ideal $P$ of $D$. Then the number of elements in $D/P^e$ is $p^{ef}$ where $D/P$ has $p^f$ elements.

The authors point out that $P^{e-1}/P^e$ is a subgroup of $D/P^e$ and has $p^f$ elements, and then go on to state that by induction the proposition is true. I do not see how induction works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex notes, you can replace $D$ by the localization $D_P$ without changing anything. Then $P$ becomes principal, and it is very easy to prove that $P^{r}/P^{r+1}$ is isomorphic to $D/P$ for all $r$. Now you can use the short exact sequences $$0\to P^{r}/P^{r+1}\to D/P^{r+1}\to D/P^{r}\to0$$ and induction to get what you want. Indeed.from this exact sequence we see that $$|D/P^{r+1}|=|P^{r}/P^{r+1}|\cdot|D/P^{r}|=|D/P|\cdot|D/P^{r}|$$

Comment: This is roughly what I said in my linked post. It's probably good to have this self-contained though :)

Comment: I didn't know what an exact sequence so I didn't understand that portion in your answer until Makoto Kato provided his explanation which is simply the same thing, but approaching it from a simpler algebra perspective.

Comment: Mariano, why we can replace $D$ by the localization $D_P$ ?

Comment: Because the quotients $D/P^r$ and $D_P/P_P^r$ are the same.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez you can explain more, the isomorphism $D/P^r\cong D_P/P^rD_P$ don't imply that $D$ is DVR !!

Comment: Why would that isomorphism imply that $D$ is a DVR? Where did I say to does?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : you say that we can replace $D$ by $D_P$ so  $D$  is DVR !!

Comment: No. What I wrote is that it is enough to assume that $D$ is a DVR. The quotient $D/P^r$ is isomorphic to $D_P/P^RD_P$, and the latter is a module over $D_P$, which *is* a DVR.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: ah yes , of course.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's basically the idea. Note that $D/P^e\cong D_P/P^eD_p$ so you might as well assume that $D$ is a DVR. Then, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587409/ring-of-integers-of-local-fields/587634#587634) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since $D \supset P^{e-1} \supset P^e$, $|D/P^e| = |D/P^{e-1}| |P^{e-1}/P^e|$.
Hence, using induction on $e$,  it suffices to prove that $|P^{e-1}/P^e| = p^f$.

Since $P^e \subset P^{e-1}$ and $P^e \ne P^{e-1}$, there exist $\alpha \in P^{e-1} - P^e$.
We define a map $f\colon D \rightarrow P^{e-1}/P^e$ by $f(x) = \alpha x$ mod $P^e$.
This is a homomorphism of abelian groups.
Since $f(P) \subset P^e$, $f$ induces a homomorphism $g\colon D/P \rightarrow P^{e-1}/P^e$
It suffices to prove that $g$ is an isomorphism.

We first prove that $g$ is injective.
There exists an ideal $I$ such that $\alpha D = P^{e-1} I$.
$I$ is not divisible by $P$.
Suppose $f(x) \in P^e$, i.e. $\alpha x \in P^e$.
It suffices to prove that $x \in P$.
Suppose otherwise.
$\alpha xD = P^{e-1} I x$.
Since $I x$ is not divisible by $P$, $\alpha x$ is not divisible by $P^e$.
This is a contradiction.

Next we prove that $f$ is surjective.
It suffices to prove that $\alpha D + P^e = P^{e-1}$.
Since the only prime ideal containing $\alpha D + P^e$ is $P$,
$\alpha D + P^e$ is of the form $P^k$.
Clearly $k \ge e -1$.
Suppose $k \ge e$.
Then $\alpha \in P^e$.
This is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks, can you show how the equality in your first line holds true, i.e. the one about the number of elements in the cosets

Comment: Assuming $|D/P^e| = |D/P^{e-1}| |P^{e-1}/P^e|$ is an easy proof, your answer to my original question is excellent and easily accessible

Comment: @animalcroc Let $G$ be an abelian group.
Let $H,  K$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $G \supset H \supset K$.
Let $f\colon G/K \rightarrow G/H$ be the canonical homomorphism.
The kernel of $f$ is $H/K$.
Hence $(G/K)/(H/K)$ is isomorphic to $G/H$.
Hence $|G/K|/|H/K| = |G/H|$, i.e. $|G/K| = |G/H||H/K|$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the canonical homomorphism between those factor groups. What is it?

Comment: @animalcroc $f$ is defined by $f(x + K) = x + H$ for $x \in G$.

Comment: well done. I felt there was a more elementary proof, and here it came